# android SharedPreferences how set multiple object and get

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created `HashMap<String,Object>` type i have added these map SharedPreferences  but how can i get all object from SharedPreferences.

following is my code

```
Map<String,Object> sevalistmap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(sevalistmap);
                SharedPreferences pref =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cart", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                pref.edit().putString("cartdetail", json).apply();
```

when i trying to access object from map it throws an error

```
SharedPreferences pref =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cart", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String storedHashMapString = pref.getString("cartdetail", "");
        java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType();

        HashMap<String, Object> testHashMap2 = gson.fromJson(storedHashMapString, type);

        ArrayList<ListDTO> sevalist=new ArrayList<ListDTO>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : testHashMap2.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();

            ListDTOdto=(ListDTO)entry.getValue();
            sevalist.add(dto);
        }
```

how can i retrieve object and set to ListDTO

Comment: What error did it throw?

Answer (score 0):

Check TinyDb lib.

http://tinydb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

For example for Integer List:

//To save

```
public TinyDB tinyDB;
public ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
tinyDB = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
tinyDB.putListInt("indexesList", indexes);
```

//To load

```
indexes = tinyDB.getListInt("indexesList");
```